# How to configure sonar-project.properties for multiple languages(Python and html)?

Tags: python, html, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I am setting up Sonarqube for one of my projects which is a mix of Python and Html. I am able to configure the project separately for either of these languages but not together. Is there any way to do this? I tried the following scenario

1)**sonar.language is commented in sonar-project.properties**

sonar.projectKey=DemoProject

sonar.projectName=Demo Project

sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=.

Sonar.language is commented

## #sonar.language=py,web

Output: - But Sonarqube is only analyzing the html (web) files

Can anyone suggest how to configure **sonar-project.properties** for multiple languages(Python and html)?

Comment: What version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: Sonarqube 4.5.5

Comment: and with no `sonar.language` value in your properties file, you only get a mono-language analysis?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Could you please suggest a solution for multi language analysis?

Comment: What you've described (assuming the answer to my previous question was 'yes') should work. You should double-check your analyzer-level settings to make sure you don't have something unexpected in there.